# Assert a property from list object as null using Java 8

Tags: java, junit

This is my mock response, where I need to assert a particular field (type) as null. It always throws me exception as

```
   java.lang.AssertionError: expected null, but was:<[null]>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotNull(Assert.java:755)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNull(Assert.java:737)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNull(Assert.java:747)
```

Mock response

```
{
"locations": [
 {
  "type": null,     
  "statusDt": "2018-08-15",
 
   }
  ]  
}
```

I'm doing assertion in the followig way

```
    assertNull(locationResponse.getLocations().stream().map(location -> location.getType()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: @Mahesh_Loya, the syntax is wrong. Pls check

Comment: The result of `collect(Collectors.toList())` is always a List, never `null`. This List may be empty, or contain null entries - in your case one entry that is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like as a result of `collect()` operation you get a *List* that contains only one element `null`.
Please try to get first element from that list

```
assertNull(locationResponse.getLocations().stream().map(location -> location.getType()).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0));
```

Answer (score 4):

The message of the assertion says that `null` is expected but `[null]` is observed: `[null]` is an array that contains a single `null` element.

I think that `collect(Collectors.toList()))` cannot return a `null` object.

You should write an assertion like this one to check that all the types are `null`:
`assertTrue(locationResponse.getLocations().stream().map(location -> location.getType()).allMatch(type -> type == null));`

Answer (score 0):

Consider an assert on each type, such as (working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/gists_java/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_64573724)):

```
locationResponse.getLocations()
                .stream()
                .map(location -> location.getType())
                .forEach(t -> assertNull(t));
```